# Diagonalization and change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, change-of-basis

My question arises from a quantum mechanical problem about perturbation theory, but it is of algebraic nature. I'm a bit forgotten about some basic notions of algebra and I need help in the following:

I have the following matrix, written on a certain basis $\left|1\right\rangle$ and $\left|2\right\rangle$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
E_0 &-A \\ 
-A & E_0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Eventually I found the matrix eigenvalues $E_I=E_0-A$ and $E_{II}=E_0+A$ and eigenvectors $\left|I\right\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\left|II\right\rangle=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}$.
I found out in the solutions of further problems that I can write these vectors as $\left|I\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|1\right\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|2\right\rangle$ and $\left|II\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|1\right\rangle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|2\right\rangle$.
Why is that?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because$$|I\rangle=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}+\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\frac1{\sqrt2}|1\rangle+\frac1{\sqrt2}|2\rangle$$and$$|II\rangle=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}-\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\frac1{\sqrt2}|1\rangle-\frac1{\sqrt2}|2\rangle.$$

Comment: But why are $\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$ and  $\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$  the original basis?

Comment: Because the coordinates of $|1\rangle$ with respect to the original basis are $1$ and $0$ and the coordinates of $|2\rangle$ with respect to the original basis are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Of course, if I calculate the matrix elements with such basis I get the same values of the matrix as expected. So, the orthonormal basis is always a basis of any matrix? Obrigado pela paciência! I've to brush some very trivial concepts of algebra urgently.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates of a vector relative to some basis are just the coefficients of the corresponding linear combination of the basis vectors. Taking your first eigenvector, its coordinates relative to the basis are $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and $\frac1{\sqrt2}$. This means by definition that $$|I\rangle = \frac1{\sqrt2}|1\rangle+\frac1{\sqrt2}|2\rangle.$$